# Checking div is hidden by other two buttons

Tags: javascript

I have three buttons on screen, only one of the three have a class called 'show_hide'.  When 'show_hide' is called, it make a div show.  However the other two buttons do not make reset show_hide to hidden.
How do I make the other two buttons reset the show_hide to hidden when they are pressed?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
    $(".show_hide").hide();
});
```

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous. You have three buttons. Let's say they have id's "btn1","btn2","btn3". btn1 show/hides the div. Do btn2 and btn3 simply set btn1's state to hidden (and hide the dive, maybe?). A little more context here would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could had a class to your other button '.hideBtn' and catch the click to do the hide:

```
$(".hideBtn").click(function(){
  $('.show_hide').hide();
})
```